# Timer Implementation not Running every 5 seconds as intended c#

Tags: c#, timer

I have the following timer implementation. But the timer is not running every 5 seconds as needed. How can make this run every 5 seconds. At present its running about once in 30 seconds.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            msgsent = 0;
            timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
            timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
            bool isenable = timer.IsEnabled;
            timer.Start();
        }

private async void timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
        {
            if (geo == null)
            {
                geo = new Geolocator();
            }

            Geoposition posi = await geo.GetGeopositionAsync();

    if (posi.Coordinate.Point.Position.Latitude <= 12.9227 && posi.Coordinate.Point.Position.Longitude >= 080.1320)
                {
                    if (msgsent <=1)
                    {
                        msgsent = msgsent + 1;
                       ShowDialog(new MessageDialog("Your Bus has crossed xyz"));
                    }

                } 

        }
```

Comment: Every time you click the button you add a new event handler and start the timer again, which is ... awful, and something you probably don't intend.  Wherever you construct `timer`, move all code except `timer.Start()` there.  And who knows how long it takes your async call to complete?  You can't guarantee it returns within 5 seconds.  Better to halt the timer on timer_Tick called, then restart it at the end of the timer_Tick method, and don't worry about it running every 5 seconds exactly.

Comment: Any help on possibly how to structure this the best possible way would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a hint.  If you understand where each goes, then it should be clear.  If not, you will once you get better.

```
// in the class definition
int msgsent;
Timer timer;
```

and

```
// in the constructor
timer = new Timer();
timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
```

and

```
// in the Button.Click event handler
timer.Start();
```

and

```
// in the Timer.Tick event handler
timer.Stop();
/* do your work here */
timer.Start();
```

There will be further issues when the user is clicking the button while you're doing your work, but that's beyond the scope of this question.